# Session timeout in spite of setting the session time in web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I have an ASP.net website where I am facing a session timeout issue. In `web.config` I have set session timeout to 480 (8 hours as session time). But even then session does not stay that long; it goes out after a number of minutes. Why is that and how I can fix it? My site is hosted on a shared hosting server.

Answer (score 1):

By default Session time in asp.net is 20 min, and we can change it by setting Web.config file.
Now in your case you are setting it to 8 hours but went out in 1 min.

Do you know that there are few point by which session can be time out?

***)** When it is wrongly configured in Web.Config file.

***)** We can set this time out in server (IIS) also, so if its default setting is changed.

***)** When the total memory of session is higher that the assign in shared host.

***)** When there are some internal error at run time in any page, then session will be lost.

***)** When some one or any process is changingadding any aspx file or web.config file at runtime.

So check all these point. I am sure it will resolve your problem...

Answer (score 1):

Also, have you checked the app pool recycling options?

Comment: Peter how I can check it ? please guide ?

Comment: @haansi - for IIS6: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1eee28e2-b319-4b4e-8267-a8c0aa0dcf36.mspx?mfr=true  ...for IIS7: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/recycling

Answer (score 1):

Your hosting provider have probably set some low value in "Recycle worker processes" in IIS for your application pool. Not sure if they can change that for you but you could try to ask them.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reason which cause your session timeout before the actual value configure in web.config file.

one such reason is that if you hosted your applcation and forgot to reset the app pool after deployemnt.

or

once you deploy the application for first time then its corresponding app pool may get reset dusring the first run of application.

or if your app pool may get crash in between the process..

You can diagnose this problem first check your app pool (in advanced settings- if you hosted your application in IIS) now by going to the Event Viewr and check the logs in Custom Views go to server role then find the log by clicking find button at right side pane and paste your app pool name in search box.

check for the error or warning message related to app pool.

i hope this ma help you